# Python Detecting STDIN During raw_input()

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

When designing a small, interactive menu, often times you might see output appear while the user is attempting to input. For example:

**Scenario**: The user is typing in the command "tasklist" and, while he is typing, a warning will appear telling hin that his hard drive space is low.

```
Welcome to My Program
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
Otherwise, type a command below.

Menu >
```

Then:

```
Welcome to My Program
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
Otherwise, type a command below.

Menu >taskError: Hard Drive Space @ 90%
list
Menu > [Executing 'tasklist']
```

It doens't seem to alter the input in any way, but is there a way to detect that and potentially clear out the raw_input from that point?

Comment: Does your program print "taskError: Hard Drive Space @ 90%" or does some O/S process print it? If the OS, what OS are you using?

Comment: My program is vastly different to this, but the assumption is that it is printing from another thread within the context of the main process.